# Creating a HUD for PokerStars using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, hud

I want to create a HUD for PokerStars similar to Holdem Manager:

[Screenshot](http://www.winallpoker.com/wp-content/uploads/pokerstars-hud.jpg)

I'm using Visual Studio and C# language, and Windows 7 64-bit. The HUD will show some boxes with some information. The boxes must be draggable and semi-transparent, and the user can set their opacity. When the mouse hovers one of these boxes, additional information is displayed. I have no control over the PokerStars window that will have the HUD, that is I cannot edit it in Visual Studio.
I need some advices about how to achieve this, and what is the best way to do this.

My first attempt was about using Windows Forms with SetParent function via PInvoke, but transparency is not working:

My HUD is just a set of semi-transparent boxes that must provide additional information to the window they are attached to. The problem is that I cannot make my hud element semi-transparent when it is inside another application's form. My hud element is a box that inherits from the Form class. It's nothing but a borderless form (BorderStyle is set to "None", 100% opacity) with some colored labels inside, no code was added when creating it. So, I have a main form class called Form1 and another form class called HUDBox which is the hud element I want to display inside Form1. Both inherit from the Form class.
If I set HUDBox object's opacity to anything less then 100%, the HUDBox object just won't display inside Form1 object. I also tried using TransparencyKey, SetWindowLong and SetLayeredWindowAttributes via PInvoke but it makes everything transparent, not just the HUDBox object. Here is the code:

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace MyHUD
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static Form1 mainForm;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            mainForm = new Form1();
            HUD psHUD = new HUD();
            Application.Run(mainForm);
        }
    }
}
```

HUD.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;

namespace MyHUD
{

    class HUD
    {
        private static int HOW_MANY_HUDBOXES = 4;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        private List<HUDBox> hudBoxes = new List<HUDBox>(HOW_MANY_HUDBOXES);

        public HUD()
        {
            initHudBoxes();
        }

        private void initHudBoxes()
        {
            for (int hb = 0; hb < HOW_MANY_HUDBOXES; hb++)
            {
                HUDBox newHudBox = new HUDBox();
                hudBoxes.Add(newHudBox);
                //SetParent(newHudBox.Handle, Program.mainForm.Handle);
                newHudBox.Show();
            }
            UserControl1 control = new UserControl1();
            SetParent(control.Handle, Program.mainForm.Handle);
            control.Show();
        }

    }
}
```

Code for HUDBox.cs and Form1.cs are not relevant as they are simple auto-generated Forms. This program adds 4 copies of my hud element inside the main form. My Form1 class is just for testing, it will be replaced by the external PokerStars window.
Opacity works fine for my hud boxes when I don't use the SetParent function, because they are not set as Form1's children.

I've also tried to use a UserControl instead of my HUDBox form:
UserControl1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyHUD
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(127, 0, 0, 255);
        }

        private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I've manually added this UserControl1 to Form1 using VisualStudio, and it shows fine with correct opacity, but then I added another UserControl1 via SetParent and the transparency doesn't work:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDchg.jpg)

I've also tried to use combinations of the following functions but nothing worked, the transparency applied to the whole window instad of just the hud elements inside it:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hwnd, uint crKey, byte bAlpha, uint dwFlags);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

        public const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
        public const int WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000;
        public const int LWA_ALPHA = 0x2;
        public const int LWA_COLORKEY = 0x1;

        //set the window style to alpha appearance
        private void setWindowOpacity(IntPtr handle, byte opacity)
        {
            SetLayeredWindowAttributes(handle, 0, opacity, LWA_ALPHA);
        }

        private void setWindowLayered(IntPtr handle)
        {
            SetWindowLong(handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) ^ WS_EX_LAYERED);
        }
```

Is there a way to make my hud elements children of the PokerStars window keeping the correct transparency?

Is there another way for creating this HUD, maybe by using GDI?

Comment: The first screenshot is HoldemManager HUD (the small black boxes near each player), the second screenshot is my Form with the semi-transparent blue rectangle (UserControl1) working correctly as it was added via Visual Studio, and the other 100 percent opaque blue rectangle (another UserControl1) was added calling the SetParent function, but it only shows when its opacity is 100 percent, cause it won't show if its opacity was any value below 100 percent.